# ios objective C Bool not setting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, boolean

im creating a custom UITextField, but is not setting a BOOL??

MyCustomTextField.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OMTextField : UIControl <UITextFieldDelegate>

{
    UITextField *_theTextField;

    BOOL _hasBackGroundImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)UITextField *theTextField;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasBackGroundImage;

@end
```

MyCustomTextField.m

```
#import "OMTextField.h"

@implementation OMTextField

@synthesize theTextField = _theTextField;
@synthesize hasBackGroundImage = _hasBackGroundImage;

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [_theTextField release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.theTextField = [[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)]autorelease];
        //self.theTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
        self.theTextField.text = @"textField";
        self.theTextField.delegate = self;

        if (self.hasBackGroundImage) {
            NSLog(@"lo tienes");
        }
    if (!self.hasBackGroundImage) {
        NSLog(@"nana tienes");
    }

        [self addSubview:self.theTextField];


    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

and the call in my MainVC:

```
MyCustomTextField *textField = [[[MyCustomTextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 160, 150, 40)]autorelease];

    textField.hasBackGroundImage = YES;

    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    textField.theTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;


    [self.view addSubview:textField];
```

so it shows fine,
but as you see im setting  `textField.hasBackGroundImage = YES;`

but when executed, i see the message for BOOL = NO??

```
nana tienes
```

So what Im I missing?, why is this not evaluated as YES??

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've placed your NSLog in the initWithFrame method.  This is called on the line before you set textField.hasBackGroundImage, when the value is still NO.

If you want to see this value get set, add the following method to MyCustomTextField:

```
- (void)setHasBackGroundImage:(BOOL)flag
{
    _hasBackGroundImage = flag;
}
```

Then put a breakpoint on this method.  You should see it hit as soon as you set it.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `initWithFrame:`, which prints "nana tienes" because the default value for a `BOOL` is `FALSE` (or `NO`). Then, you set it to `YES` *after*.

If you place the test after you set it to `YES`, it will print "lo tienes".